# Equivalent vb.net code

Tags: c#, vb.net

i am new to asp.net.Can you post an equivalent vb.net code following the C#.net code.
Thanks

```
public string  getSecureCookie(HttpRequest Request)
{
    HttpCookie secureCookie = Request.Cookies["Test"];
        if(secureCookie!=null)
    {
        return secureCookie.ToString();
    }
    else
        {
            return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run through the code translator available at http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/

```
Public Function getSecureCookie(ByVal Request As HttpRequest) As String
    Dim secureCookie As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("Test")
    If (Not (secureCookie) Is Nothing) Then
        Return secureCookie.ToString
    Else
        Return ""
    End If
End Function
```

Might want to use `If secureCookie IsNot Nothing` instead, though. But the translator does work.

Comment: It's a bit more idiomatic to use IsNot Nothing in VB as opposed to "Not (test) is Nothing)"

Comment: Yeah, I just caught that myself...I just pasted the output of the translator directly without wanting to edit it though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Public Function getSecureCookie(ByVal request as HttpRequest) As String
  Dim cookie = request.Cookies("Test")
  if cookie IsNot Nothing Then
    return cookie.ToString()
  Else
    return ""
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Beat me by a couple minutes. I'd give you +1 but I'm out of votes!

Comment: @lc, it happens.  I don't mind loosing to a correct answer ;)